# Prove that a differentiable function with a special propriety is a Isometry

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

*Hi folks! I'm trying to answer this one exercise:*

Let $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ be a $C^1$ function such that, for all $x\in\mathbb R^m$ $|f'(x)\cdot v|=||v||$ (where $||\cdot||$ is the euclidean norm).
Show that $||f(x)-f(y)||=||x-y||$.

$\bullet$ *Using the Mean Value Inequality, it's easy to see that $||f(x)-f(y)||\leq||x-y||$*.

$\bullet$ This exercise was on the Inverse Function Theorem section.

*I'm stuck trying to prove that $||f(x)-f(y)||\geq||x-y||$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch - feel free to leave comments or ask further questions.

- Since you want to apply the inverse function theorem, you could perhaps begin by verifying that at every $x \in \mathbb R^m$, the linear map $f'(x)$ is invertible. (It should be possible to get injectivity from the fact that $|| f'(x) v || = || v ||$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^m$; surjectivity then follows on dimensional grounds.)
- Having done this, the inverse function theorem tells us that around every $x \in \mathbb R^m$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $f : U \to f(U)$ is bijective. Furthermore, we learn that the local inverse function $g : f(U) \to U$ is also continuously differentiable, and its derivative at a given point $y \in f(U)$ is $ g'(y) = (f'(x))^{-1}$, where $x \in U$ is the point such that $f(x) = y$.
- Having found this expression for the derivative of $g$, you can now show that $g$ obeys a similar condition to $f$, i.e. $|| g'(y) w || = || w ||$ for every $y \in f(U)$ and for every vector $w \in \mathbb R^m$. Applying your mean value theorem argument to $g$ instead of $f$, you should be able to prove that $||f(x_1) - f(x_2) || \geq || x_1 - x_2 ||$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in U$, which is very close to what you asked for!
- Unfortunately, we've only shown that $f$ is *locally* an isometry, i.e. we've only shown that we can cover $\mathbb R^m$ with open sets $U_\alpha$ such that for each $U_\alpha$,  we have $ ||f(x_1) - f(x_2) || = || x_1 - x_2 || $ for all $x_1, x_2 \in U_\alpha$. We need to turn this into a *global* statement, valid for all $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^m$. One strategy is to observe that, since $f$ is locally an isometry, $f$ maps short line segments to line segments of the same length - but then, $f$ also maps long line segments to line segments of the same length, because long line segments can always be broken down into short line segments. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150583/isometry-in-mathbbrn) for more details.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks very much @Kenny Wong